# Getting the value of a paper-radio-button

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I have the following code

```dart
      <paper-radio-group
        id="marital-status-group"
        on-change={{changeHandler}}>
        <paper-radio-button name='Married' label='Married'></paper-radio-button><br>
        <paper-radio-button name='Divorced' label='Divorced'></paper-radio-button><br>
        <paper-radio-button name='Single' label='Single'></paper-radio-button><br>
        <paper-radio-button name='Visiting' label='Visiting'></paper-radio-button>
      </paper-radio-group>

  void changeHandler( CustomEvent e )
  {
     print ( ( e.target as PaperRadioButton ).label );
  }
```

When the button with label="Divorced' is clicked, the following is the result

```dart
Divorced (http://localhost:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12)
```

All I need is the 'Divorced' NOT the other part in parenthesis.
If I should click another button, then both selections are printed.

Something is wrong. What are the correct options please.

Comment: I think `selected` is what you are looking for - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735215

Comment: selected does not work for me. This radio-button is suppose to be simple, yet it value retrieval does not seem to be simple. I think that the examples of paper-elements and core-elements should have snippets demonstrating how real values are retrieved from each widget. After all, the UI might look good but when one has to struggle to find what is supposed to be simple, it does add unnecessary frustration.

Comment: You shouldn't forget these elements are developer preview not stable and all still work in in progress. 
I'll take a look again, I think I still have the example somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think your example works as expected - even as expected by you ;-)  `(http://localhost:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12)` is only added by the `print()` method.

```dart
print((e.target as PaperRadioButton).label == 'Male');
```

prints

```dart
false (http://localhost:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12)
true (http://localhost:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12)
```

depending on which element you select. Therefore you can just use the label value in your code.

I don't know why `print()` adds this though.
In the `<app-element>` which I used for this test it adds different text depending on where I print

```dart
AppElementConstructor (:1)
attached (:1)
ChangeEventhandler (http://localhost:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12)
```

(I'm already used to `(:1)` but the `.../polymer.js:12` is new to me. I suppose it is some kind of zone or isolate info.

#### Info

The `selected` attribute of the `paper-radio-group` is bound to the `name` attribute of the selected `paper-radio-button`

```dart
  <paper-radio-group
    id="marital-status-group"
    selected="{{selectedName}}">
    <paper-radio-button name='Married' label='Married'></paper-radio-button><br>
    <paper-radio-button name='Divorced' label='Divorced'></paper-radio-button><br>
    <paper-radio-button name='Single' label='Single'></paper-radio-button><br>
    <paper-radio-button name='Visiting' label='Visiting'></paper-radio-button>
  </paper-radio-group>
```

and in the Dart code of your element

```dart
  @observable String selectedName;

  void selectedNameChanged(old) {
    // do something when the another radio button got selected
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter. However I cannot find a name property in the paper_radio_button class at [http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/paper_elements/0.0.1/index.html#paper_elements/core_elements-paper_radio_button.PaperRadioButton](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/paper_elements/0.0.1/index.html#paper_elements/core_elements-paper_radio_button.PaperRadioButton). Hence `e.target as PaperRadioButton).label` gives the warning _There is no such getter 'name' in 'PaperRadioButton'_. Im still using polymer 0.12.0-dev and Dart Editor version 1.6.0.dev_03_00 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.6.0-dev.3.0

Comment: I haven't checked yet but I updated my answer tho show how you can use it. You should also be able to access it like `e.target as PaperRadioButton).attributes['name'];`

Comment: In my experimenting I found that `on-click='radioSelection'` and `radioSelection( e ) { print( e.target as PaperRadioButton ).label; ) }` prints only the current selection. I don't know if the behaviour will be consistent but it seems to accomplish the same thing as the use of attributes[ 'name' ] above. I had read somewhere in my search (cannot find the link now ) that it is ill-advisable to access an attribute directly as done above. Is that fear warning?

Comment: I'm not a ware of such a best practice. `attributes['xxx']` works on every element no matter if the attribute is implemented but allows only `String`. `element.name` works only if the element has such an field defined in the class but allows every type compatible with the type annotation of the field (if any)

Comment: FYI: The best solution is what Günter describes in the Info paragraph. Set the name field on the paper-radio-button and bind selected to a string field in the crontroller.